# List to priority queue

Tags: c++, list, iterator, priority-queue

I have a college programming project in C++ divided into two parts. I beggining the second part where it's supposed to use `priority_queues`, `hash tables` and `BST`'s.

I'm having trouble (at least) with priority queues since it's obligating myself to redone a lot of code already implemented in the first part.

The project it's about implementing a **simple airport management system** and, therefore, I have classes like Airport (main class), Airplane, Terminal and Flight. My airport had a `list` of terminals but now the project specification points out that I must **keep the terminals in a** `priority_queue` where the top contains the terminal less occupied, i.e has less flights.

For each class, I have CRUD functions but now how am I supposed, for example, edit a terminal and add a flight to it? With a list, I just had to iterate to a specific position but now I only have access to object in the top of the queue. The solution I thought about was to copy the priority queue terminals to a temporary list but, honestly, I don't like this approach.

What should I do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know how to retrieve an item from a priority queue? Do you know how to insert into a priority queue? What are the requirements for your user interface exactly? Why, exactly, do you think you are being required to keep the `Terminal` s in a priority queue?

Comment: @Karl Knechtel: `top()` to retrieve first element, `push` to insert an element and `pop` to remove the first element. I need to have CRUD functions for every class in the implementation. The system has to let the user to do all the typical actions you would if you had a airport to manage: **create** `airplanes`, **create** `flights`, **create** `terminals`, **associate** `airplanes` and `flights`, **associate** `flights` and `terminals`. Where I wrote 'add', it can be replaced by the other **CRUD** functions (read, update and delete).

Comment: When you must use a priority queue, can you only use a priority queue? Or are you allowed to store pointers to the terminals in both a priority queue and a hash table or BST?

Comment: @outis: Currently, I have `list<Terminal*> terminals_` which should be, with the new project requirements, something like `priority_queue<Terminal*> terminals_`. The ideal would be keeping the list and having the priority queue, but the specification states to **not use redundant information and maintain data consistency**.

Comment: Keeping pointers to the terminals in multiple collections shouldn't produce redundant information, but adding/removing flights could cause inconsistency in the priority queue (unless it's a dynamic priority queue, which `std::priority_queue` isn't, though you could always extend it). Are you sure that with the priority queue, users are supposed to be able to add flights to arbitrary terminals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you need a priority queue with efficient increase and decrease key operations. You might be better of creating you own your own priority queue implementation.

The priority_queue container is great for dynamic sets. But since the number of terminal in an airport are pretty much fixed you can a fixed size container with the heap family of algorithms.

As the internal storage, you could use any container that provides random access iterators (vector, array, deque). Then, use make_heap(), sort_heap() family of functions to heapify the array. Now you can cheaply access the top(), modify the priority of a random member in the heap and iterate through all elements easily.

For an example see:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/make_heap/