# Random access priority queue

Tags: c++, priority-queue, random-access

Continuing [List to priority queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4416724/list-to-priority-queue)

I'm implementing a improved priority_queue with random access.

```
template <class T, class Container = std::vector<T> >
class Heap {
public:
    Heap() {}

    Heap(const Container& container) {
        container_ = container;
        std::make_heap(container_.begin(), container_.end());
    }

    Heap<T, Container>& operator=(const Heap<T, Container>& heap) {
        if (this != &heap)
            container_ = heap.container_;

        return *this;
    }

    void push(const T& x) {
        container_.push_back(x);
        std::push_heap(container_.begin(), container_.end());
    }

    void pop() {
        std::pop_heap(container_.begin(), container_.end());
        container_.pop_back();
    }

    const T& top() {
        return container_.front();
    }

    const Container& getContainer() const {
        return container_;
    }

    T& operator[](size_t n) {
        return container_[n];
    }

    typename Container::const_iterator begin() const {
        return container_.begin();
    }

    typename Container::const_iterator end() const {
        return container_.end();
    }

    size_t size() const {
        return container_.size();
    }

    T& base() {
        return container_.back();
    }

    Container::iterator erase(Container::iterator position) {
        return container_.erase(position);
    }

private:
    Container container_;
};
```

Am I taking the right way?

- Fixed the unary constructor.
- Improved code.

Comment: If it's random access, it's no longer a priority queue.

Comment: It's supposed to behave like a priority_queue but with the possibility of random access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't look that great to me:

- The unary constructor should take argument by const reference.
- The assignment operator doesn't check for self-assignment.
- The `getContainer()` method shows a lack of clarity in the interface - why would you simply expose the implementation detail like that?
- Most importantly: why do you want a "random access priority queue"?

Comment: I've fixed the unary constructor. I don't understand your second statement and I'm gonna fix the third point. About your question, it's for a college project that, as you can see, is badly structed.

Comment: Thanks for the great link. I updated my code. Is it better? Sorry for the inconvenience but it's the first time I do something like this.

Comment: one possible reason to want this is to iterate through the queue's elements (i.e. peek at further contents). I always find `std::stack<>` to be particularly painful as it doesn't allow you to examine it's contents. I always switch back to using the underlying vector directly.

Answer (score 1):

Your pop() method can violate the heap ordering. Use pop_heap() instead of pop_back(). I can't seem to find any other bug right now.

You can easily test such an implementation by pushing in a random integers and pop() them one by one. You should get them back in sorted order. This is known as heap sort.

Suggestions:

- Instead of returning a ref to the container you could implement an const iterator to this class.
- Note that you should not change the key of the randomly accessed element because it may destroy the heap structure. If you need such functionality you should implement a change_key function which would change the key safely and maintain the heap ordering.

Comment: @Renato: your `begin()` and `end()` methods return `Container::iterator`. They should always return `Container::const_iterator` or someone can (read: *will*) mess up your heap.

Comment: @André: Thanks! I changed the methods. Anything else that I should improve?