# Maintaining a ordered (by an argument, int) collection

Tags: c++, list, collections, structure

Inexperienced with c++ structures: I need a structure that fills the following:

Can hold about ~100, I'd say 500 at max objects (each which might be very big in memory: containing clips of images)

Ordered by an int the object has: I want it so I say "Add this object with priority 2. And then add this object with priority 3!", and have the collection be (Object w/Priority 3, Object w/Priority 2), so as to iterate it from the start, starting from the objects with highest, to lowest, priority.

Does not need deletion (could be handy, but not a requirement)

Need to be able to access the objects inside, anywhere they be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a [priority queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue). In C++ it's implemented as `std::priority_queue` and [here's an example](http://comsci.liu.edu/~jrodriguez/cs631sp08/c++priorityqueue.html).

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that I need to be able to access the objects inside, in case it changes anything. My bad!

Comment: How do you want to access them? By some unique key? If so, then you can keep them in a hash table in addition to the priority queue.

Comment: There's a similar question about a random-access priority queue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4422933/random-access-priority-queue